# Fix for the catastrophic backtracking in the regex expression

Tags: regex

I have encountered the following regex in the company's code base.

`(?:.*)(\\bKEYWORD\\b(?:\\s+)+(?:.*)+;)(?:.*)`

Breakdown of Regex:

1. Non Capturing group: `(?:.*)`
2. Capturing group `(\\bKEYWORD\\b(?:\\s+)+(?:.*)+;)`

   2.1 Non Captuing group: `(?:\\s+)+`

   2.2 Non Capturing group: `(?:.*)+`
3. Non Capturing group: `(?:.*)`

The above regex goes into catastrophic bactracking when it fails to match `;` or the test sample becomes too long. Check below the two test samples:

```
1. --      KEYWORD the procedure if data match between Type 1 and Type 2/3 views is not required.
2. KEYWORD SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '***FAILURE : '||V_G_ERR_MSG_01; /*STATEMENT TO THROW USER DEFINED ERROR CODE AND EXCEPTION TO THE CALLER*/
```

I went though [Runaway Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)'s article aswell and tried to use to `Atomic Grouping` but still no results. Can anybody help me how to fix this regex ?

Comment: `(?:.*)+` seems to be the issue as it translates to "find something or nothing one or more times". Change it to `(?:.*)`

Comment: See updated comment

Comment: Also, `(?:\\s+)+` can be just `(?:\\s+)`. I hope they fired whoever wrote that garbage.

Comment: `(?:.*)` can also be just `.*`

Comment: Actually, all the non-capture groups are superfluous. Try `.*(\\bKEYWORD\\b\\s+.*;).*`. Even just `(\\bKEYWORD\\b\\s+.*;)` should be fine

Comment: Your regex is effective just this: `(\\bKEYWORD\\s+[^;]*;)` which will not cause any backtracking

Comment: You're only interested when a semi-colon exists after "KEYWORD" on the same line, right? So example 1 should be ignored?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus extactly.

Comment: Then the regex provided by @anubhava is the most efficient.

Comment: That of course assumes that each sample is processed one at a time. If the samples exist all in the same text file such as a log then `(\\bKEYWORD\\s+[^;\\r\\n]*;)` would be proper. See https://regex101.com/r/yiB9O5/1 because @anubhava would match too much; see https://regex101.com/r/yiB9O5/2

Comment: The pattern that you might use is `".*?\\bKEYWORD\\s.*;).*"`. However, it is still not that fast. anubhava's regex does not meet the same requirements (does not match the whole string, does not match all text from `KEYWORD` till the last `;`). Depending on real requirements, it may be optimized further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link you provided, there are patterns like `(x+x+)+` in your expression: `(?:\\s+)+` and the subsequent `(?:.*)+`. The first matches one or more whitespace characters one or more times, and the second matches indefinite amount of any chars one or more times. This hardly makes sense.

Non-capturing groups are unnecessary here.

Use

```
.*\\b(KEYWORD\\s.*;).*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZPyNZD/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KEYWORD                  'KEYWORD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```